# What is the MAX number if I store int(255) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, int

I use int(255) in mysql as my id. Is this long enough? If I got about 1,000,000 records....Thank you.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Something is probably just converting that to `int(11)` for you. Since you can't have 255 visible digits in an `int`, the maximum value will be `2147483647`.

If you need more than that you can set it to be unsigned, since I'm assuming you have no negative ids and then you can have up to `4294967295`.

If you are ever going to have more than 4 billion records (very unlikely if you're at 1 million right now), then you could use a `bigint` instead, which allows you to store numbers up to `18446744073709551615` at a cost of more storage space of course.

Comment: it means, I type 255 is useless?

Comment: Yes, no integer will be displayed as 255 characters. The longest is (11) which is enough for a `-` symbol and 10 digits. If you are using unisigned int then you might as well set it to int(10)

Answer (score 8):

-2147483648 to 2147483647 as per the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) for a signed 32 bit integer value

The 255 is simply display width and doesn't affect the range of values

Answer (score 6):

The `INT` in `mysql` use 4 byte storage, and range from **-2147483648 to 2147483647**. If you use unsigned int, the range is **0 to 4294967295**.

Answer (score 6):

See [this blog](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2010/05/mysql-maximum-value-of-integer.html).

```
SELECT ~0 as max_bigint_unsigned
,      ~0 >> 32 AS max_int_unsigned
,      ~0 >> 40 AS max_mediumint_unsigned
,      ~0 >> 48 AS max_smallint_unsigned
,      ~0 >> 56 AS max_tinyint_unsigned
,      ~0 >> 1  AS max_bigint_signed
,      ~0 >> 33 AS max_int_signed
,      ~0 >> 41 AS max_mediumint_signed
,      ~0 >> 49 AS max_smallint_signed
,      ~0 >> 57 AS max_tinyint_signed
\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
   max_bigint_unsigned: 18446744073709551615
      max_int_unsigned: 4294967295
max_mediumint_unsigned: 16777215
 max_smallint_unsigned: 65535
  max_tinyint_unsigned: 255
     max_bigint_signed: 9223372036854775807
        max_int_signed: 2147483647
  max_mediumint_signed: 8388607
   max_smallint_signed: 32767
    max_tinyint_signed: 127
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 5):

If unisgned, from 0 to 4 294 967 295, so that is more than eough.

More info [in mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html).

Comment: @Deele: the docs (*the ones you linked to*) state that INTEGER is signed by default and that UNSIGNED is optional (and non-standard)

Comment: @gbn, did you find it hard to read first two words in my answer?

Comment: Not at all. I find it hard to believe that you mentioned "unsigned" when 1. it isn't the default 2. OP didn't mention it. So *what value does your answer add*? None. It's based on at best an assumption: Occam's razor tells you it's default signed.

Comment: @gbn, The question was not about any standarts, but was about specific situation. If guy does not know data types and is mentioning INT and that he wants to use it for ID field, that means, guy does not know SQL and I gave newbie advice to use unsigned value for ID's and mentioned how many fields it can hold... The value of answer is in advice, I gave... C'mon, this is turing into nonsense....