# What would be the most efficient way to query large amounts of dynamic profiles in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a usersystem. Every user has a profile. Profile fields are dynamically stored in the database. The database looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE profileFields(
    profileField_id INT(255) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    profileField_name VARCHAR(255),
    profileField_value VARCHAR(255),
    profileField_type VARCHAR(255),
    profileField_isOptional TINYINT(1),
    PRIMARY KEY(profileField_id)
);
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id INT(255) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_username VARCHAR(255),
    user_password VARCHAR(255),
    user_email VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
);
CREATE TABLE profileValues(
    profileValue_id INT(255) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    profileValue_profileField_id INT(255),
    profileValue_user_id INT(255),
    profileValue_value VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(profileValue_id)
);
```

I'm trying to get a list of all users with all profile fields and values.
I've got a total of 50.000 users and 60 profile fields, resulting in 3.000.000 profile values.

What would be the most efficient way to retrieve such a list (and possibly perform searches based on the profile fields)?

Comment: Please provide an example of the data you want to produce.

Comment: I can't see how the tables are related to each other. How are you supposed to join? 50.000 * 60 = 3.000.000, but that seems two be only two of the tables?

Comment: Do all profiles have all 60 values? because if so, you dont need to break it down further,

Comment: @jarlh looking at this information, it looks like `profileValues` is the top table, but i cant see the 60 x 50,000 part either

Comment: The 3M records must be in  profileValues already.

Comment: If you show us some ways, we'll tell you which is most efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "most efficient" way is always going to be difficult to identify. Try these for starters:

1. Many of the values in profileValues.profileValue_value will be repeated so you might consider creating a table which holds all the possible strings (perhaps a growing list of them) and turning the field into an int. This can then be indexed for very efficient searching without having to do 3M rows.
2. profileValues does not need a PK on profileValue_id; consider a PK of (profileValue_user_id +  profileValue_profileField_id). This will ensure joins are more quickly indexed.

You also need to check this: [What is the MAX number if I store int(255) in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171312/what-is-the-max-number-if-i-store-int255-in-mysql)