# MySQL data type "int" exceeding limits

Tags: mysql, database

Using MySQL as a database.We have a table where a column is "int" data type. Its exceeding the limit of int type i.e. 4294967295. 
Is there any solution to get more entries/values for the same.
We don't want to have a downtime for more than an hour.

Changing it to Bigint type has been considered but focus is to lessen the time.

Comment: just change the dataType in mySQL to BIGINT

Comment: yes and it still will take 3-4 hours.

Comment: you got no choice.. except you change it to decimal round up value

Comment: Your server has a speed limit. 3-4 hours sounds pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be:

- ALTER TABLE original_table to original_table_old
- CREATE TABLE with the same layout as the current table but then with a new data type (BIGINT) for the offending column (let's call this one original_table_new)
- `CREATE VIEW original_table AS SELECT * FROM original_table_old UNION SELECT * FROM original_table_new` and use that view for your queries.

That is fast, the VIEW could hamper performance pretty much depending on your mysql version (5.7 should be ok).

Answer (score 0):

When your value is long you can't use INT type. You need to change it relevant type. There is more explanation about your problem in StackOverflow

> What is the MAX number if I store int(255) in MySQL? [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171312/what-is-the-max-number-if-i-store-int255-in-mysql)
>
> What is the size of column of int(11) in mysql in bytes?[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes)